# Four-current, Induced Charge and Magnetic Flux

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism

I'm studying Jackiw's "Fractional Charge and Zero Modes for Planar Systems in a Magnetic Field" DOI: [10.1103/PhysRevD.33.2500](http://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.29.2375)

but I have difficulties at some points. One of the problems is

$$\langle j^0\rangle=\pm\frac{e}{4\pi}B$$

where $j$ is four-current, $B$ is magnetic field. How can I derive this result (and why we used only $j^0$ component)?.

Comment: The link is to the Erratum, which contains a single paragraph noting an error in invoking an argument and no equations. Could you update with the correct link?

Comment: I fixed the link.